# Swift Table index out of Range

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and have set up a table which fills using data from an sql database.

The table loads fine but occasionally it gives the error:

> "Fatal Error: Index out of range".

It doesn't happen all the time just every now and again.

Also I have migrated from parse to using sql and http requests. Have I taken the correct approach to this when populating the data into the table?

Any help much appreciated!

```swift
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    var tableData = [String]()
    var tableImages = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


          }



    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {

        self.tableView.hidden = true

          self.tableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.tableImages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        var nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell3", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell3")


        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "********.php")!)


        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{
            (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?)-> Void in


            let str2 = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)



            let str3 = Int(str2!)!





            let url = NSURL(string: "********")!

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if let urlContent = data {



                    do {

                        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)


                        print(str3)

                        var i = 0

                        while i < str3 {

                        print(jsonResult[i]["title"]! as! String)
                            print(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)

                            self.tableData.append(jsonResult[i]["title"]! as! String)
                            self.tableImages.append(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)

                            i = i + 1

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            })

                        }

                    } catch {

                        print("JSON serialization failed")

                    }


                }


            }

            task.resume()




             });


            print(tableData)


          self.tableView.hidden = false


        }

    }


    // 2
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {




        return self.tableData.count
    }


    // 3
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {
        let cell: TblCell3 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3") as! TblCell3
        cell.lblAffiliate.text = tableData[indexPath.row]


        let url3 = NSURL(string: "https://www.********.co.uk/\(tableImages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]).png")
        cell.affiliateImage.sd_setImageWithURL(url3)


        return cell
    }

    // 4
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }

    // 5
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 400
    }





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps. I changed a couple small things around for better code (half could be considered bias). I think the issue is mostly that you were reloading the tableView in the loop. Everything else was just a slightly better way to handle this case. I put everything in viewDidLoad, and made the tableView load empty input prequel to receiving data. I think this is more standard for handling this scenario. If you need any other help let me know.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var tableData: [String] = []
    var tableImages: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
            var nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell3", bundle: nil)
            tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell3")

            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "********.php")!)

            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{
                (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?)-> Void in

                let str2 = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let str3 = Int(str2!)!
                let url = NSURL(string: "********")!

                let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                    if let urlContent = data {
                        do {
                            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                            self.tableData = []
                            self.tableImages = []  
                            for i in 0..<str3 {
                                self.tableData.append(jsonResult[i]["title"]! as! String)
                                self.tableImages.append(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)
                            }

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("JSON serialization failed")
                        }
                    }
                }
                task.resume()
            });
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {
        let cell: TblCell3 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3") as! TblCell3
        cell.lblAffiliate.text = tableData[indexPath.row]


        let url3 = NSURL(string: "https://www.********.co.uk/\(tableImages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]).png")
        cell.affiliateImage.sd_setImageWithURL(url3)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 400
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your call to `reloadData()` is inside the `while` loop in which you are building `tableData` and `tableImages`. Move that after the `while` loop, by which point both of those arrays will be fully populated.